# PHP: file_get_contents(): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed - HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to get channel's data from the twitch API and... for some reason it always fails :X This is the error I always get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/diesel1521?client_id=******): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Filename: page/home.php

Line Number: 7
```

I will give you a live example: `http://91.139.176.200/`
Page code:

```
$channel = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($this->streamer->getStreamerDisplayName($this->_id, true).'?client_id=******'), true);
```

the only variable used will always return a streamer's display name from the database. Using CodeIgniter, latest version. If anyone is asking, I have openssl, http and https enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the url in a browser and look at the response:

```
{"error":"Unprocessable Entity","status":422,"message":"Channel 'diesel1521' is unavailable"}
```

The error comes from the fact that the channel you are requesting is unavailable.

Comment: Ohhh... this channel was blocked due to tos violations... thanks a lot, should add a check for this asap ^-^